# RabbitMq message causes server to crash, leading to infinite retry

Tags: c#, .net-core, rabbitmq

We use rabbit mq to send messages to a server for processing.

We require the server to ack a message. That way if the server happens to die whilst processing the message, we will retry the message when it restarts, or with a different server.

The problem is, on a very rare occasion, we will get a message that deterministically crashes the server. This is because we call into some open source native dlls, those dlls have bugs, and sometimes these dlls just cause the process to crash with no exception. Of course it would be ideal to fix those bugs, but we don't expect to fix all such issues in pdfium or opencv any time soon. We have to reckon with the fact that whatever we do, we will eventually get such a message.

The result of this is that the message is then retried, the server restarts, picks ups the message, crashes, and so on ad infinitum. Nothing gets processed till we manually stop the server, and purge the message. Not ideal.

What can we do to solve this problem?

What we don't want to do is create another service that monitors the rabbitmq service, looks for such messages and purges them, since that just leads to spiralling complexity. Instead we want to deal with this at the rabbitmq client level. We would be perfectly happy to say that if a message is not processed 3 times, we should just fail the message. We could do this by maintaining a database entry of which messages we've processed, but ideally I wouldn't want to involve anything external, and just contain the solution to this problem in our rabbitmq client library. I'm not sure how to do this though.

Comment: Could you set a [TTL on the message or the queue](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html), or perhaps record the message Id and number of times you've tried to process it on the server *prior* to actually processing it, so that you can abort if you've tried more than 3 times?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @Diado. A TTL wont work, since eg. a server could be down for a day for maintanence, and then we'll want to process the message once it  starts up. As I said, we could record the message ids, but that requires maintaining a database entry, and ideally i'd like to make this solution be handled entirely by our rabbitmq client, rather than requiring every one of our services to communicate with the db to process a message.

Answer (score 4):

One method I have used in my event driven architecture is to use dead letter exchanges (DLXs) or poison queues, that way if we see the same message multiple times due to service failure then it'll be pushed into the DLX instead of being re-queued into the original exchange. These messages then trigger a different type of process within our system to alert us messages are stuck and failing to process, we can then diagnose and fix the consumer. After a fix has been made we trigger another process to move the poison messages back into the original exchange to be then processed as normal.

In your scenario because your process crashes there is two possible options to deal with these messages:

1. If the message is marked as redelivered then clone the message and add an attempt count to the body or as a header (`x-attempt-count`) to the message. The copy will then be added to the back of the queue with the attempt count. When the copy is then consumed you can check if it hits the threshold and then move the message into a DLX or store in a database. The major drawback here is that it breaks the order of which the messages are processed.
2. Use an external services to keep track of the number of delivery attempts, I would recommend using something like redis/memcache where you can increment a counter based on a unique message id. At the start of your process if the message has been marked as redelivered then lookup the counter. If the message has reached the threshold, trigger a different process again like moving it into a DLX.